# Looped animation in ImageView

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I have an ImageView in my screen and I want to make it shake (rotate left and then rotate right).
I know how to animate an ImageView, this is my code:

```
new RotateAnimation(20f, 50f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
anim.setDuration(700);

// Start animating the image
final ImageView splash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mobileshake);
splash.startAnimation(anim);
```

The problem is, right now the Imageview is looping one animation, but I want 2 animations to loop (rotate left and then rotate right).

How can I do this?

Sorry for my bad English..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by doing the following and works very smooth :)

```
final RotateAnimation anim1 = new RotateAnimation(20f, 50f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        anim1.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        //anim1.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        anim1.setDuration(300);

        final RotateAnimation anim2 = new RotateAnimation(50f, 20f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        anim2.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        //anim2.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        anim2.setDuration(300);

        final ImageView splash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mobileshake);
        anim1.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){

            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                splash.startAnimation(anim2);
            }

            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }});
        anim2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){

            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                splash.startAnimation(anim1);
            }

            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }});

        splash.startAnimation(anim1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine two (or more) animations using an [`AnimationSet`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html).

There is an example of a "Shake" animation in [API Demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/index.html) using `TranslateAnimation` defined in xml. You can achieve the result you are looking for by following a similar approach.